# Does the original Zelda theme ever play in Skyward Sword?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I've been playing the newest Legend of Zelda game on the Wii, Skyward Sword, but I'm really missing the main Zelda theme:

Does this music play at any time during the game?

Comment: ahh the memories

Comment: I don't remember hearing the theme at all in the game.

Comment: @JeffMercado It is in the game, see my answer...

Answer (score 10):

There are two times I can recall the music:

> The Song of the Hero has bits of it, and it plays straight-up as part of the credits.

Comment: What bits of it can you hear in the Song of the Hero? Just listened to it again and I don't recognize any part... http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=acDvui4bzSk#t=56s

Comment: That particular rendition only has the first rising line a few times, but when you actually play it in the designated spot it has more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEodDj-ktEc

Comment: Oh. nice, I guess I've noticed it but forgot

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about that one completely.

Answer (score 7):

It does play, at least once

> Over the end credits...

Comment: Oh that might be why I never heard it, once I beat the game (the first time) I just switched to my TV to watch something to let it roll.  Went back to the game after a long enough time.

Comment: Well, the credits are worth watching, they show extra scenes of Zelda alone and after them there is a short scene.

Comment: Now that I think about it more, I think I actually left the game running (didn't switch to TV) and went onto the computer (which is sitting right next to the TV).  I remember seeing what happens (in the corner of my eye) but I wasn't really paying too much attention to the music.